# Vue 3 external component/plugin loading in runtime

Tags: vue.js, webpack, vue-cli, vuejs3

I am designing an architecture for the `Vue 3` app with distributed module-based ownership. Module system will be represented with plugins (seems like the most appropriate solution allowing `vuex` module and `vue-router` dynamic injects). Each such module/plugin will be developed by dedicated team working within isolated repos. We cannot use `npm` package-per-plugin approach as deployment process should be isolated as well, and with `npm` approach core app team will have to rebuild app each time `npm` package plugin has updates. This means we will have to load such plugins/pages at runtime via `http`.

So far [this approach](https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/distributed-vue-applications-loading-components-via-http/) by Markus Oberlehner seems like some sort of the way to go - it uses custom `Promise` based solution for `webpack`'s missing "load external url script at runtime" functionality. While it works fine with `Vue 2`, `Vue 3` gives `VNode type: undefined` error.

The above mentioned article offers the following `webpack` external component loading solution:

```
// src/utils/external-component.js
export default async function externalComponent(url) {
    const name = url.split('/').reverse()[0].match(/^(.*?)\.umd/)[1];

    if (window[name]) return window[name];

    window[name] = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.async = true;
        script.addEventListener('load', () => {
            resolve(window[name]);
        });
        script.addEventListener('error', () => {
            reject(new Error(`Error loading ${url}`));
        });
        script.src = url;
        document.head.appendChild(script);
    });

    return window[name];
}
```

But above, as I said, does not work with `Vue 3` `defineAsyncComponent` mechanism.

```
// 2.x version WORKS
const oldAsyncComponent = () => externalComponent('http://some-external-script-url.js')

// 3.x version DOES NOT WORK
const asyncComponent = defineAsyncComponent(
    () => externalComponent('http://some-external-script-url.js')
)
```

So I have two questions:

1. Are there any known better solutions/suggestions for above architectural specification?
2. Is there any working `webpack` dynamic external import solutions tested with `Vue 3` out there?

UPD: Here is small [reproduction repo](https://github.com/markoffden/sample-vue3-runtime-component-load)

Comment: Hello Denys, Markus here. Can you provide a reproduction Git repo? Just tested it with Vue 3 and it works for me.

Comment: Hi @moriartie , I have added the repo link in the ticket description. Thanks for willing to have a look)

Comment: @markoffden would  you be willing to jump in https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/240683/vue-external-components chat and help me at some point?  I'm trying to go down a similar route but I'm running into issues.

Comment: @DavidTorrey sorry, was on NY holidays vacation far from laptop :) I can add that back then we chose not to update to Vue 3. We also used `single-spa` package. Then I've left the project so don't have much more to share, AFAIK team is happy with above approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We solved this problem together via chat.

Components built via the Vue 3 vue-cli rely on `Vue` being available in the global scope. So in order to render components loaded via the technique described in my article, you need to set `window.Vue` to a reference to `Vue` itself. Then everything works as expected.

Comment: Please have a look at this follow up question about dynamically including the url of one of these external precompiled .js files in a Vue component that loads the components. Cheers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64584561/how-can-i-load-an-nested-component-dynamically-in-vuejs-without-hardcoding-the-u

Comment: @moriartie is there a working git repo example?  I've set window.Vue but for the life of me still having all kinds of errors

Comment: @DavidTorrey no, no repo. But nowadays I highly recommend looking into webpack module federation for similar functionality!

Comment: @moriartie thanks for the look.  It somewhat works (i can get it to load) but the interactivity doesn't seem to work (for instance v-bind and v-model, even just within the remote component itself), so I'll need to find an alternative I think.  What I'm trying to accomplish just might not be feasible

Comment: your answer is not good enough ! say it in clear way –

Answer (score 2):

update：

If import vue from `vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler` and set to global, then no need to change webpack / Vite config, and no need to load vue from cdn.

```
import * as Vue from 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler';
window.Vue = Vue;
```

---

Besides setting `window.Vue`, some other webpack or Vite configuration should also be set, otherwise some error is presented in console: `vue warn invalid vnode type symbol(static) (symbol)`

Vue3 + webpack:(https://github.com/vuejs/vue-next/issues/2913#issuecomment-753716888)

```
// index.html:
 <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@3.0.4"></script>

 // vue.config.js
  configureWebpack: config => {
     ...
    config.externals = { vue: 'Vue' }
    ...
  }
```

Vue3 + vite:(https://github.com/crcong/vite-plugin-externals)

```
// vite.config.js
import { viteExternalsPlugin } from 'vite-plugin-externals'

export default {
  plugins: [
    viteExternalsPlugin({
      vue: 'Vue'
    }),
  ]
}
```

Comment: I'd like to add this, but it would be nice to know more, like specifically how you load it on a razor page.