# Load dynamically a vuejs library and render the component on it

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a vuejs app as a container for multiple other "apps".
The idea was to:

- have a generic code to discover/load components
- build the other apps as vuejs lib in order to be able to load component on it

On my first lib, I have this main.js:

```
import HelloRadar from './components/HelloRadar.vue'
export default HelloRadar
```

and this component, HelloRadar:

```
<template>
  <div>
    Hello from radar !
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'HelloRadar'
}
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
</style>
```

Now, on my main app, I have this code:

```
<template>
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li v-for="module in modules" v-bind:key="module" @click="loadModule(module)">
                {{ module }}
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</template>

<script>

    import axios from 'axios';

    export default {
        name: 'HelloWorld',
        data() {
            return {
                modules: [],
                selectedModuleMenu : null,
                selectedModuleApp : null
            }
        },
        created: function () {
            axios.get("/orbit/api/modules").then((response) => {
                var modulesList = response.data;
                this.modules = modulesList;
            });
        },
        methods: {
            loadModule: function (moduleName) {
                this.loadExternalComponent("/modules/" + moduleName + "/"+ moduleName + ".umd.js");
            },
            loadExternalComponent : function(url) {
                const name = url.split('/').reverse()[0].match(/^(.*?)\.umd/)[1];

                if (window[name]) return window[name];

                window[name] = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
                    const script = document.createElement('script');
                    script.async = true;
                    script.addEventListener('load', () => {
                    resolve(window[name]);
                    });
                    script.addEventListener('error', () => {
                    reject(new Error(`Error loading ${url}`));
                    });
                    script.src = url;
                    document.head.appendChild(script);
                });

                return window[name];
            }
        }
    }
</script>

<!-- Add "scoped" attribute to limit CSS to this component only -->
<style scoped>
</style>
```

The issue is that the function loadExternalComponent seems not working. I got this js error in console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'createVNode' of undefined

> Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Chaining cycle detected for promise #

I have picked this method from here https://markus.oberlehner.net/blog/distributed-vue-applications-loading-components-via-http/

Do you have some idea how to make this kind of app ? Does using lib is the right way ? Thanks for your help

Answer (score 0):

I think there's an answer to your question:

> Components built via the Vue 3 vue-cli rely on Vue being available in
> the global scope. So in order to render components loaded via the
> technique described in my article, you need to set window.Vue to a
> reference to Vue itself. Then everything works as expected.

*Markus Oberlehner*

@moriartie (Markus Oberlehner) has already worked that out with @markoffden: [Vue 3 external component/plugin loading in runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63581504/vue-3-external-component-plugin-loading-in-runtime)

Comment: Thanks Muka, however I am now wondering how to access to the Vue instance since in Vue3 there is no more the Vue object in vue ?