# How can I load an nested component dynamically in Vuejs without hardcoding the url

Tags: vue.js, code-injection, dynamically-generated

I followed Markus Oberlehner for loading Vue components via http. We have a Vue component precompiled as a .js file hosted on a separate server. When the user navigates to this loader component below, the call to externalComponent() successfully fetches the .js file and renders the component on this page. That is great. This only works if we hardcode the url in the loader component.

We are building a plugin architecture into our site. We have written some single page Vue component files. Each of these files is a plugin. We precomiled these .vue files into .js files according to Markus Oberlehner's helpful tutorial here: https://github.com/maoberlehner/distributed-vue-applications-loading-components-via-http.

We also have a Vue component in our main site - let's call it the loader component - that fetches a .js file and renders it into a component using the externalComponent() method - demonstrated in Markus's tutorial. This works, but since the MyComponent is a constant defined outside of the loader component's data object, we cannot dynamically inject the plugin_id of from the vue router into the .js file's url.

If you're curious why our urls don't end in `.js` it is because we are passing a url to an endpoint in our server instead. This endpoint fetches the .js file and returns it to our client.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <MyComponent />
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import util from "~/js/util.js";

let MyComponent = () =>

  /* If we hadcode the url, the page renders no problemo.
   *
   * util.externalComponent("http://localhost:8081/api/plugins/167/code");
   */
  
  /* However, we'd like to fetch the plugin_id from the Vue router and inject that into the argument 
   * as I've tried to achieve in the line of code below. 
   *
   * The following code does not work because Vue apparently loads the MyComponent element in the DOM
   * before executing the created() hook. We get the error "plugin_id is not defined."
   */
    util.externalComponent(
      "http://localhost:8081/api/plugins/" + plugin_id + "/code"
    );


export default {
  name: "plugin",
  components: {
    MyComponent
  },
  data() {
    return {
      plugin_id: null
    };
  },
  created() {

   /* This line does indeed populate the plugin_id data variable, although this happens after the 
    * page attempts to load MyComponent
    */
    this.plugin_id = this.$route.params.plugin_id;
  }
};
</script>
```

So, how can we modify this code to dynamically insert the plugin_id into the url?

This is a nuxt project by the way.

---

Update

Here is an approach that works the first time I load the page, but consecutive loads are still a problem. Specifically, the first component just loads again regardless of whatever the new plugin id may be.
But this looks like the right direction...

```
<template>
  <div>
    <component v-bind:is="component" v-if="loadedUrl"></component>
    {{ plugin_id }}
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import util from "~/js/util.js";

export default {
  name: "plugin",
  props: [],
  data() {
    return {
      loadedUrl: false,
      component: null
    };
  },

  beforeRouteEnter(to, from, next) {
    next(vm => {
      vm.loadedUrl = false;
      vm.component = () =>
        util.externalComponent(
          "http://localhost:8081/api/plugins/" + to.params.plugin_id + "/code"
        );
      vm.loadedUrl = true;
      next();
    });
  },
  beforeDestroy() {
    //does not seem to help.
    console.log("in beforeDestroy");
    this.component = null;
  }
};
</script>
```

Comment: use `props` https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html

Comment: But how can this line of code which is above export default {...} know what the props are? Please provide an example.

Comment: I am updating my question with an approach that works the first time I load the page, but consecutive loads are still a problem. Specifically, the first component just loads again regardless of whatever the new plugin id may be.

Comment: I'd try to use `watch()` instead. Something like `watch: { '$route.params.plugin_id': { handler() { this.component = () => /* ... */ }, deep: true, immediate: true } }`